# Taking payment from customer's card and giving to merchant

Tags: paypal, paypal-permissions

I am creating a booking site, where the public can make bookings and then pay using their card. I want to take the card details and send them to PayPal via their REST api, and then send the amount to a merchant who will be one of our customer's selling the booked product.

Is this possible to do? PayPal documentation is confusing at best. I currently have the card payments being taken successfully and paid into our own 'developer' account, but what I can't seem to find is how to credit the money to a PayPal account that isn't our own instead.

I have looked into the PayPal Permissions API but again the documentation is unclear, and I don't see where I specify the merchants id or email address when calling RequestPermissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do can be accomplished by using PayPal's Adaptive Payments product (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/). Unfortunately, Adaptive Payments are not currently available with REST APIs. So if you have the option of going with classic APIs, this is currently available to you.